# How to design a scalable restful / Non-restful API?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, restful-architecture

I have an API 'x' which does a CRUD on 4 params today - a, b, c, d. Tomorrow if I have to support few more params in the same API, due to change in requirement, then what is the best way to handle it?

Should I go ahead and update my DB with the new params introduced and continue doing this everytime there is a change in the requirement?

One of my peers suggests that the API should accept a JSON Object which can accept any set of params and any set of key-value pairs. Every time I get a new set of key-value pair via this JSON, I update my params table with this value and then the requirement can change as and when they want.

I think that this will be very difficult to maintain across clients as the API will literally accept any key-value pair and hence one platform might debate on sending these key-value pairs in one format while the other would be willing to send it in another format. Also, it will be hard to put in validations and check on optional and mandatory params.

Any leads is appreciated

Comment: @TimHutchison Please do not suggest other SE communities if you do not understand what they accept as a good question. If this were to be posted on Software Engineering, it would receive down votes and close votes very quickly because it is overly broad. This leads to a poor user experience - when a user follows advice yet does not achieve a positive outcome, it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

My answer has a bit of nuance, so beware.

I find that in practice we don't make that many changes to our API's, and when we do, we can often do it in a way where it's backwards compatible. This does mean we add optional fields.

If you control all clients, it's also fairly easy because you can just upgrade all of them so it's not really an issue.

It's harder when you make changes more often, or are doing more than just adding some properties, and it's 3rd parties connecting to you, you can easily upgrade them.

There's more than 1 way solve this, but my recommendation is the follow github's model.

For bigger breaking changes they change the `Content-Type` header. Currently the `Content-Type` for github requests is:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json
```

Before they made a big breaking change it was:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v2+json
```

For experimental API's that are prone to change they use an experimental `Content-Type`:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.mister-fantastic-preview+json
```

Generally this idea is preferred for restful design, but it's not the only solution.

Comment: Pardon me for my experience in API designing, how does changing header help me handle new params in the same API, in future. Can you give an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically what I'm suggesting is versioning your api. Once you introduce new BC-breaking changes, you change to a different Content-Type. When you receive PUT requests with this new Content-Type, you validate the new schema. When you get a GET request with this mime-type in the Accept header, you give them the new format, not the old one.

Comment: Versioning is one way, yes! Can you also explain if what my peer suggests is right approach or not?

Comment: @alchemist on the cuff I would say that your peer's solution is absolutely absurd and a really bad idea. It's a good idea for your API to be extremely strict and always error when the slightest thing is wrong and not magically adapt. One disclaimer is that I don't fully know your requirements or your system and maybe it's an exceptional situation. My first inclination is to call this a major red flag.

Comment: and what approach would you suggest to design the schema for a situation like I have mentioned in the question?